# Dependency injection in a project that can be used by other projects in a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a visual studio solution which includes multiple projects (Hosts.Project1, Hosts.Project2):

[image]

The startup class in each of these project solutions looks as follows:

```
        public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
        {
          private IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
          public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
          {
            var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var configurationRoot = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                    azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

            configurationBuilder.AddConfiguration(configurationRoot);
            configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{configurationRoot["keyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

            _configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
            builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IConfiguration), _configuration));

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IARepo, ARepo>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBRepo, BRepo>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILogRepo, LogRepo>();
        }
    }
```

Each of these project solutions require "keyVaultName", access to "LogRepo". Only the following section differs in each startup class:

```
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<IARepo, ARepo>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBRepo, BRepo>();
```

How do I create a new project solution (Hosts.ProjectCommon) which includes a common startup class (with keyVaultName, acces to LogRepo) and I can refer to this common startup class from other project solutions & reuse the common startup class and only update the dependency injection code in individual project solutions?

Comment: What is a "project solution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have one visual studio solution with multiple individual application projects kinda like:

```
Solution
|__> Hosts.Project1 (requires <IARepo, A1Repo>)
|__> Hosts.Project2 (requires <IARepo, A2Repo>)
```

You could utilize inheritence to extract the common configuration calls into a base class and override the calls to the specific registration.

Your solution would look like this

```
Solution
|__> Hosts.Project1 //(requires <IARepo, A1Repo>)
    |__> RegistratorApp1 : BaseRegistrator
|__> Hosts.Project2 //(requires <IARepo, A2Repo>)
    |__> RegistratorApp2 : BaseRegistrator
|__> Hosts.Base //(includes base configuration)
    |__> BaseRegistrator
```

The actual code for these individual classes might look a little something like this:

*(mind that these 3 classes are actually located in different projects. As indicated in the snippet above)*

```
public class BaseRegistrator {
  public BaseRegistrator(){}
  private IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
  public void Register(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
  {
    var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var configurationRoot = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

    configurationBuilder.AddConfiguration(configurationRoot);
    configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{configurationRoot["keyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

    _configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
    builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IConfiguration), _configuration));

    RegisterApplicationDependentServices(builder)

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILogRepo, LogRepo>();
  }

  protected virtual void RegisterApplicationDependentServices(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder){

  }
}

public class RegistratorApp1 : BaseRegistrator {
  public RegistratorApp1(){}

  protected override void RegisterApplicationDependentServices(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder){
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IARepo, A1Repo>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBRepo, B1Repo>();
  }
}

public class RegistratorApp2 : BaseRegistrator {
  public RegistratorApp2(){}

  protected override void RegisterApplicationDependentServices(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder){
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IARepo, A2Repo>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBRepo, B2Repo>();
  }
}
```

In your individual startup classes you now only have to create an new instance of either RegistratorApp1  or RegistratorApp2 and call the base register method (which in turn calls the overridden/specific RegisterApplicationDependentServices implementation)

```
//startup of Hosts.Project1
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
  {
    var registrator = new RegistratorApp1();
    registrator.Register(builder);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Questions - 1) currently I have a Registrator class and Startup class. Is it possible to avoid Registrator class and just have Startup class 2) Is it possible to avoid creating an instance of a class (var registrator = new RegistratorApp1())?

Comment: You could also rename the "BaseRegistrator" to "BaseStartup" (not technically necessary) and derive the Startup classes in your Project1 and Project2 from this single base class. (this would remove the ProjectXRegistrator classes and the explicit instance creationg with "new Registrator...")