# Using IStringLocalizer using resources files in WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, localization, httprequest

In a WEB API in .NET 6.0, I'd like access resources based on a language. I do this :

In Startup.cs :

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddViewLocalization
        (LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "fr-BE", "nl-BE" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
});
```

The resource files are in `Resources\Controllers\` with 2 files `MyController.fr-BE.resx` and `MyController.nl-BE.resx`

In the controller :

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<MyController> _localizer;

public MyController(IStringLocalizer<MyController> localizer)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
}
```

In one of the entry point I do this :

```
public ActionResult Get()
{
    var article = _localizer["Article"];

    return Ok();
}
```

The `article` variable has these values :

```
Name = "Article"
ResourceNotFound = true
article.SearchedLocation = API.Resources.Controllers.MyController
Value = "Article"
```

In the resource file, I have for `"Article"` in `MyController.fr-BE : "Article FR"` and in `MyController.nl-BE : "Article NL"`

The request call from postman has in the header :

```
Accept-Language = fr-BE
```

Am I missed something ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your startup you misconfigured `LanguageViewLocaionExpanderFormat` to `SubFolder`. It should be `Suffix`, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.languageviewlocationexpanderformat?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

`LanguageViewLocaionExpanderFormat` has two options:

1. SubFolder: Locale is a subfolder under which the view exists.
2. Suffix: Locale is part of the view name as a suffix.

The sub folder would have a file structure: `Resources/controllers/fr-BE/filename.resx`
Whilst The suffix would have the following structure: `Resources/controllers/filename.fr-BE.resx`. Where `filename` should be the name of the controller.

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddViewLocalization
        (LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

Your resources should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: filename.fr-BE.resx the "filename" have to have a specific name ?

Comment: Oh yes the filename should be the name of the controller

Comment: No change I still get "Article" instead "Article NL" or "Article FR"

Comment: what does your resource file look like? Do you simply do `key` | `value`? I will update my answer with a picture

Comment: That's work. I forget to change the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture to the one I want.

Comment: I have a bonus question. This code is in the API project, but I'd like to inject by DI in the Application project but IStringLocalizer is unknow in this project but I think I can add a package but from there I don't have access to the controller. It's a clean architecture.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62446250/18278998) help